# Installing Windows 10 on OS X Yosemite with BootCamp

Tags: macos, boot-camp, windows-10-preview

I am trying to install Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro, the late 2011 model, using BootCamp. However, with all of the videos I have seen there is an option in Boot Camp Assistant that says "Create a Windows 7 or later version install disk", but my computer does not show this. My MacBook does have a CD Drive. How do I make this option appear?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem trying to use Bootcamp on my MBA (late 2010 model) after I did a clean install of Yosemite. With this version I no longer have the option to use an ISO to make a bootable USB drive (and I never had the option to install anything newer than Windows 7). The fix is easy.

---

Open `Terminal.app` and elevate privileges:

```
sudo -i
```

Edit:
`/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/Info.plist`:

```
nano /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

In the "`Win7OnlyModels`" section, delete the string containing your model’s name (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`. (When prompted: Press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save the changes).

You'll need to sign the modified file or Boot Camp won't work:

```
codesign -fs - /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app
```

---

**Note:** You’ll be prompted to install `codesign_allocate` if it’s not already installed. After the installation, you’ll need to run the `codesign` command again.